# Carousel in Angular5

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, angular5

I am trying to make a carousel slide in angular. I took the html and css from (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/carousel/).
But I didn't know how to use the javascript in the site.
This html in `app.component.html`

```
 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <img class="first-slide" src="../assets/imgs/i1.jpg" alt="First slide">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="carousel-caption text-left">
                                <h1>Example headline.</h1>
                                <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida
                                    at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                                <p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="second-slide" src="../assets/imgs/i2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
                                <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida
                                    at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                                <p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="third-slide" src="../assets/imgs/i3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="carousel-caption text-right">
                                <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
                                <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida
                                    at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                                <p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
```

The carousel isn't working, neither the next and previous buttons. Any help, i can't figure out why.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You did not add bootstrap to your project correctly.

**Install Bootstrap 4 via npm:**

```
npm install --save bootstrap
```

**Add css to you main HTML file:**

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
```

You also need to add  jQuery, Popper.js and bootstrap.js

> "scripts": [   "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
>   "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/popper.js",
>   "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js" ],

Also this may help you too :https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-bootstrap/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20259918)

Comment: Yeah did think of it. Thanks